# How are objects tracked between "frames" in a functional-reactive paradigm?

Tags: reactjs, reactive-programming, elm, frp

I've been researching Elm, ReactJS and other frameworks and languages based on a reactive/functional-reactive paradigm.

I understand the basics of how reactive programming works, and why such a system might be useful. But I'm having trouble conceptualizing certain aspects in my mind.

For example, I understand the concept of the "view" or "build" function. In reactive web frameworks, we write a function that takes the state of the program and returns a list of HTML elements representing the display. Every time the state changes, the framework calls the view function again and the display is rebuilt. The frameworks are clever in that they can compare the new elements with the old elements and update the page efficiently, with the fewest calls.

However, I'm having trouble understanding how elements are tracked across calls to the view function, i.e. the frameworks knows that an element in the new frame is the same as an element in the old frame.

Why would elements need to be tracked? Because, for instance, the GUI renderer might want to play animations for checking or unchecking a box. If the framework calls the view function and rebuilds the display every time a box is checked or unchecked, the GUI renderer would have no way to know that the box wasn't created from scratch. So, it wouldn't be able to play a checking or unchecking animation.

Consider Elm's field example at http://elm-lang.org/examples/field . When a new character is entered in the field, the display is rebuilt. The textbox is created again with the new state. From the browser's point of view, it's as if the old textbox was deleted and a new one was created in its place.

Now, I think my understanding is wrong, and the textbox is not actually deleted. But how can I be sure? Does reactive programming have reliable logic for tracking elements?

Comment: It is just creating a diff. By using immutable objects one can easily compare them by equality. If they are different, you can still judge that both the old and new objects are input boxes, so that you only have to update the content of the box in the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

This is solved using the virtual DOM. A virtual version of the view is built and compared with the current version, and only changes are actually committed to the DOM. If a text field with certain characteristics exists in the virtual DOM and the actual DOM, it doesn’t get deleted and recreated, it’s just left alone, then the diffing tool moves down a level and checks the contents and properties, and so on.

These are implementation details and there’s no need to concern yourself with them, but if you want to know more about how diffing works, you can read about Elm’s VirtualDom package [here](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/virtual-dom/2.0.4/VirtualDom)